# Fitting two overlapping sinusoids in a single set of data

Tags: fitting, data, envelope

I have a set of data

```
data = Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/aqUwN2XR", "List"];
```

that gives me a graph that looks as though it has two oscillating sinusoidal envelopes. I can plot the envelope function for the full graph:

[image]

using

```
data = Flatten[Import["Data1.xlsx"]];
ListLinePlot[{data, envtop = GaussianFilter[MaxFilter[data, 10], 10]},PlotRange -> All]
```

but it looks as if the first and third peak represent one decaying sine wave and the third and fourth peak are a separately decaying sine wave. Ideally I want to fit two envelopes, one that ignores the second and fourth peaks and one that ignores the first and third. I only want to fit this for the top envelope and don't really care about the negative values. Is there a way to do this?

Drawing of the type of fit I want:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, sure. Filter the data so that you have two datasets, each in chunks of ~100, then use `NonlinearModelFit` on both or do a single `NonlinearModelFit` with two `Sin` components in the model (or maybe a `Sin` and `Cos` sum since it looks like yours are perfectly out of phase).